# Exitting Libgdx App on Android Device

Tags: android, libgdx

When I exit my game by `Gdx.app.exit()` on android device it gives me App has stopped message

Is this a proper way to exit a libgdx app ?

and Are assets disposed by this way ? I put `Assets.dispose()` in my game class `dispose()` method

It gives me this exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput.lookUpPointerIndex(AndroidInput.java:802) at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidMultiTouchHandler.onTouch(AndroidMultiTouchHandler.java:64) at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput.onTouch(AndroidInput.java:429) at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7793) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2287) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2027) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2287) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2027) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2287) at android.view.ViewGroup.cancelAndClearTouchTargets(ViewGroup.java:2128) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2686) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:3201) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:5810) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.die(ViewRootImpl.java:5783) at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:348) at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:303) at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:84) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3776) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1407) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: That's fine. Look at the stack trace to see what the problem is. Probably an NPE somewhere. Maybe you disposed something twice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `touchDown()` method of InputListener which I used to addListener to exit button
I replaced it by `clicked()` of ClickListener and it solved the problem